# DotRas to create a VPN with Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows, vpn, dotras

I have the below code and I want to get some VPN with some settings that I need to setup:

What I need is to

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DotRas;

namespace vpnConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
         string vpnName = "VPN Essai";
         string destination = "113.244.66.3";
         string preSharedKey = "Gs0r2!-8753";

         try
            {
             RasPhoneBook phoneBook = new RasPhoneBook();
             phoneBook.Open();
             RasEntry vpnEntry = RasEntry.CreateVpnEntry(vpnName,destination,RasVpnStrategy.L2tpFirst,RasDevice.Create(vpnName,RasDeviceType.Vpn),false);

             vpnEntry.Options.UsePreSharedKey = true;
             vpnEntry.Options.UseLogOnCredentials = true;
             vpnEntry.Options.RequirePap = true;
             phoneBook.Entries.Add(vpnEntry);
             vpnEntry.UpdateCredentials(RasPreSharedKey.Client, preSharedKey);
             vpnEntry.Options.RequirePap = true;
             bool isUpdated = vpnEntry.Update();

             Console.WriteLine(@"Connection created and Updated with PreSharedKey=true, LogOnCredentials=true,RequirePap=true, RecordIsUpdated=" + isUpdated);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(@"ERROR: " + ex.Message + " Details: " + ex.Source );

                Environment.Exit(999);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I ran this code, it creates the VPN but does not keep settings I want to setup, for instance: RequirePap = true;

[Configuration as I need it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJ3HZ.jpg)

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48648353/attempting-to-set-l2tp-only-vpn-properties-in-c-sharp) might help.